# Pass values into Bootboxjs dialog confirm box

Tags: javascript, php, bootbox

I have a `PHP` foreach loop like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($student->student as $d) {
    echo
    '<tr>' 
        '<td class="StudentID">' . $d->ID . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $d->Date . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $d->Name . '</td>' .
        '<td><a class="show-confirmation">'. "click to confirm" . '</a></td>' .
    '</tr>';
}
?>
```

I am using a `bootbox js` for a dialog box like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".show-confirmation", function(e) {
        var StudentID = $('#StudentID').val();

        bootbox.confirm("Confirm, student ID? " + StudentID, function(result) {
            console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
            console.log('StudentID: ' + StudentID);
        });
    });
</script>
```

what I am trying to accomplish is when I click on `click to confirm` which has `class="show-confirmation"`, I want to get the value of `$d->ID` on the `bootbox js` confirm dialog box. Since this is a `for each` loop, I want to pass a new student id each time on the dialog confirm box.

On the confirm dialog, I want to see `Confirm, student ID?  + 15` which is the student id for that row.

**What did I do?**

- I added a variable `var StudentID = $('#StudentID').val();` hoping to fetch the student id value from the class `StudentID` eg: `<td class="StudentID">` but it is `undefined` when I am accessing it.

Could someone please kindly guide me to accomplish this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a clean way of achieving this:** 
You need to do the following:

1. Change your PHP code in order to generate the HTML structure I've shown below.
2. Set a `data` attribute on the elements to hold data that you require in code. This way you can shown fancy formatted data to user in the element's `innerHTML` and have data that can be directly used in code as data attribute values.
3. You need to reference the student that was clicked and then pick the student ID of the student. In your case you will be having multiple `<td class="StudentID">` and `$('.StudentID').val()` will not be able to identify which was the clicked item from all the student rows. Hence if you notice I have created a class called `Student` on the parent `tr`.
4. Once the click event is triggered find the parent and its children based on class names ex. `StudentID` or `Date` or `Name` and pick the data attributes you require in code.

**Below is a working sample:**

```php
# PHP CODE
<?
echo '<table>';
foreach ($student->student as $d) {
    echo 
    '<tr class="Student">
        <td class="StudentID" data-id="'.$d->ID.'">ID: '.$d->ID.' &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="Date" data-date="'.$d->Date.'">Date: '.$d->Date.' &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="Name" data-name="'.$d->Name.'">Name: '.$d->Name.' &nbsp;</td>
        <td><a class="show-confirmation">click to confirm</a></td>
    </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".show-confirmation").on("click", function(e) {
    let student = $(this).closest('.Student');
    let StudentID = student.find('.StudentID').data('id');
    let date = student.find('.Date').data('date');
    let name = student.find('.Name').data('name');

    bootbox.confirm(`Confirm, student? ${StudentID}`, function(result) {
      console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
      console.log('StudentID: ' + StudentID);
      console.log('Date:' + date);
      console.log('Name:' + name);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.5.2/bootbox.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr class="Student">
    <td class="StudentID" data-id="111">ID: 111 &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="Date" data-date="2021-01-01">Date: 2021-01-01 &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="Name" data-name="Student One">Name: Student One &nbsp;</td>
    <td><a class="show-confirmation">click to confirm</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="Student">
    <td class="StudentID" data-id="122">ID: 122 &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="Date" data-date="2021-01-02">Date: 2021-01-02 &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="Name" data-name="Student Two">Name: Student Two &nbsp;</td>
    <td><a class="show-confirmation">click to confirm</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="Student">
    <td class="StudentID" data-id="133">ID: 133 &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="Date" data-date="2021-01-03">Date: 2021-01-03 &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="Name" data-name="Student Three">Name: Student Three &nbsp;</td>
    <td><a class="show-confirmation">click to confirm</a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="Student">
    <td class="StudentID" data-id="144">ID: 144 &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="Date" data-date="2021-01-04">Date: 2021-01-04 &nbsp;</td>
    <td class="Name" data-name="Student Four">Name: Student Four &nbsp;</td>
    <td><a class="show-confirmation">click to confirm</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$('#StudentID')` is looking for an element with that as an id attribute which you have set up as a class instead.
Change to `$('.StudentID')` instead.

Comment: thank you for composing the answer. I made the changes as you suggested but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

First, you should use `.StudentID` instead of `#StudentID`. Because it is class name and not id. So, it should be.

```js
var StudentID = $('.StudentID').val();
```

And, `.val()` is used for input. It should works if your element looks like this

```html
<input class="StudentID" value="id goes here" />
```

Instead, you should use `.html()` or `.text()`. The differences is, `.html()` also return the HTML tag, while `.text()` only return the text node.

So, your JS should be look like this

```js
var StudentID = $('.StudentID').text();
```

But, the next thing is you are have bunch of StudentIDs which you will get concatenated text. So, you should use `.each()`. And also, it is quite hard to make the button can access the right id. It is because the id is not inside the button. So, your elements should have same identifiable parent element.

So, your code should look like this.

```php
<?php
foreach ($student->student as $d) {
    // add class to tr
    echo
    '<tr class="student">' 
        '<td class="StudentID">' . $d->ID . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $d->Date . '</td>' .
        '<td>' . $d->Name . '</td>' .
        '<td><a class="show-confirmation">'. "click to confirm" . '</a></td>' .
    '</tr>';
}
?>
```

```js
$(".student").each((i, el) => {
  const id = $(el).find(".StudentID").text();
  const btn = $(el).find(".show-confirmation");
  
  btn.on('click', () => {
    bootbox.confirm("Confirm, student ID? " + id, (result) => {
      console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);
      console.log('StudentID: ' + id);
    });
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### PROBLEM

1. Incorrect selector, use `.StudentID` instead `#StudentID`
2. Get text method is incorrect, use `text()` instead `val()`

### SOLUTION

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".show-confirmation", function(e) {
        var StudentID = $(".StudentID").text();

        bootbox.confirm("Confirm, student ID? " + StudentID, function(result) {
            console.log("This was logged in the callback: " + result);
            console.log("StudentID: " + StudentID);
        });
    });
</script>
```